# Shell prompt keeps old local hostname in MacOs Catalina

Tags: macos, zsh, macos-catalina

I have just received a Mac with Catalina which belonged to a former colleague.

This colleague had set the local hostname as *former-MB.local*.

I have created a new account for me (whose name is *myaccountname*) and I have set the local hostname as *myname-MB.local*. I have also deleted the account of the previous colleague.

Now, when I open a terminal, I see thath the prompt is

**myaccountname@former-MB ~ %**

I have read the possibility to change the prompt of the shell setting it in `~/.zshrc` (currently I do not have a `~/.zshrc` file), but I am wondering if it is possible to remove the memory of *former-MB* local hostname, that apparently has been saved somewhere.

Comment: Take a look at : https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/mac-help/mchlp2322/mac

Comment: @Philippe thanks for your comment, but I have already updated the local hostname to myname. Still the prompt continues to use the local hostname set by the previous user (which I have deleted).

Comment: This post may help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/30552/274760

Comment: Can you run `echo $PROMPT` ?

Comment: @Philippe  `echo $PROMPT` returns `%n@%m %1~ %# ` as expected. The command `hostname` though returns the wrong name, i.e. the name set by the previous user. As suggested by the post linked by @ Gairfowl , it may be that the command `sudo scutil --set HostName theNameISeeNow` to set the hostname to what I see now. Apparently such setting is not overridden by what you do with System Preferences->Sharing

Comment: @Picci : See the chapter _EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES_ in the zsh man page (for instance `man zshall`). You can use these format codes when setting your `PROMPT` or `PS1` variable.

Comment: @user1934428 Issue solved. See my auto-answer. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

Setting the desired hostname with the command `sudo scutil —set NewName` has solved the issue.